# Python PIL TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I keep getting this error when running a paste script in Python 3.x:
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('C:\Mine.jpg','r')
img_w,img_h=img.size
background = Image.new('RGBA', (1440,900), (255, 255, 255, 255))
bg_w,bg_h=background.size
offset=((bg_w-img_w)/2,(bg_h-img_h)/2)
background.paste(img,offset)
background.save('C:\new.jpg')
```

Error MSG:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\workspace\Canvas Imager\src\Imager.py", line 7, in <module>
    background.paste(img,offset)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1127, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

I see that there is suppose to be an integer but is getting a float in the end. What can I do to make it int instead?

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3, to get an integer result from a division you need to use `//` instead of `/`:

```
offset=((bg_w-img_w)//2,(bg_h-img_h)//2)
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that it doesn't like this line

```
offset=((bg_w-img_w)/2,(bg_h-img_h)/2)
```

so I would try something like

```
offset=((bg_w-img_w)//2,(bg_h-img_h)//2)
```

but it seems like someone just beat me to it.

Comment: Fixed it!!!

    from PIL import Image
    img=Image.open('C:\Mine','r')
    img_w,img_h=img.size
    background = Image.new('RGBA', (1440,900), (255, 255, 255, 255))
    bg_w,bg_h=background.size
    offset=(int((bg_w-img_w)/2),int((bg_h-img_h)/2))
    background.paste(img,offset)
    background.save('new.jpg')

Added int to the offset data.