# PIL resize image to exact resolution with white color for missing pixels

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I have exact (width, height) I want for my image. My image is Transparent.

What I do first is:

```
image.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

But image is still not the exact size I want. Now I want to put this resized image in center and fill it's transparent space and missing space for exact resolution with white pixels. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: you may find this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563822/how-do-you-composite-an-image-onto-another-image-with-pil-in-python

Comment: Do you want to preserve aspect ratio on your original image?  Because otherwise you can rescale it to fit exactly.