# How to insert logo in the center of qrcode in Python?

Tags: python, qr-code

I am using pyqrcode module in python and generating QR code with it. How to put the logo in the center of that QR code.

The code looks like this

```
import pyqrcode
data = "Hello World!!"

number = pyqrcode.create(data)
number.png('xyz.png', scale=int(scale))

with open('xyz.png', "rb") as f:
    return HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="image/png")
```

Or is there any another way of doing this instead of pyqrcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you composite an image onto another image with PIL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563822/how-do-you-composite-an-image-onto-another-image-with-pil-in-python)

Comment: Dont you think that qr code will create problem, if I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use a high-redundancy algorithm (eg H), you can damage the generated QRCode up to a certain percentage. H means you can cover 30% of the data and it'll still work.

That means it's just a case of placing your image over the code. The format is up to you.

[image]

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image
url = pyqrcode.QRCode('http://www.eqxiu.com',error = 'H')
url.png('test.png',scale=10)
im = Image.open('test.png')
im = im.convert("RGBA")
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
box = (135,135,235,235)
im.crop(box)
region = logo
region = region.resize((box[2] - box[0], box[3] - box[1]))
im.paste(region,box)
im.show()
```

Comment: would you mind providing reference or explanation to the croping and resizing,

Answer (score 9):

Though this question is more than 1 year old now, but still I am posting my solution as I got it working hoping that it might help someone else.

**CAUTION** I generated the qr code image in png format. To get it working, `pypng` module must be installed.

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image

# Generate the qr code and save as png
qrobj = pyqrcode.create('https://stackoverflow.com')
with open('test.png', 'wb') as f:
    qrobj.png(f, scale=10)

# Now open that png image to put the logo
img = Image.open('test.png')
width, height = img.size

# How big the logo we want to put in the qr code png
logo_size = 50

# Open the logo image
logo = Image.open('stackoverflow-logo.jpg')

# Calculate xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax to put the logo
xmin = ymin = int((width / 2) - (logo_size / 2))
xmax = ymax = int((width / 2) + (logo_size / 2))

# resize the logo as calculated
logo = logo.resize((xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin))

# put the logo in the qr code
img.paste(logo, (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))

img.show()
```

Comment: the logo can occupy how many of the area without messing the data?

Comment: @GuilhermeHenriqueMendes That I didn't check. You can check it by gradually increase the logo size until it stops scanning :)

Comment: 30% checked! =)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a much simpler way of doing this. The QRCode documentation already explains how to do this.

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil import RoundedModuleDrawer
from qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import RadialGradiantColorMask

qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L)
qr.add_data('Some data')

img_1 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer())
img_2 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask())
img_3 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, embeded_image_path="/path/to/image.png") # this one
```

https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode#styled-image

Comment: I came here because this solution doesn't work in my case. Still gave + 1 because the answer is technically correct.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done quite easily with css. Set the qr code container class to `position: relative;` and include an img / svg within that container with `position: absolute;` and transform it to the center. Restrict the size of the overlay to prevent the QR code from being unreadable.

https://jsfiddle.net/xf7d058c/

```
<!-- CSS -->
.container { width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid green; position: relative; }
.transform { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); }

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <svg height="20" width="20" class="transform"><circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#802929" /></svg>
</div>
```