# How to generate qr code with logo in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, qr-code

I have a project to generate qr code with logo in center of qr code. How I can make it like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYxUG.png)

now I'm use django-qr-code to generate text qr code but I need qr code with logo in center.

Comment: This has been asked a number of times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481990/how-to-insert-logo-in-the-center-of-qrcode-in-python for example. Please do a search before asking questions to ensure that it hasn't already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a high-redundancy algorithm (eg H), you can damage the generated QRCode up to a certain percentage. H means you can cover 30% of the data and it'll still work.

That means it's just a case of placing your image over the code. The format is up to you.

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image
url = pyqrcode.QRCode('http://www.eqxiu.com',error = 'H')
url.png('test.png',scale=10)
im = Image.open('test.png')
im = im.convert("RGBA")
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
box = (135,135,235,235)
im.crop(box)
region = logo
region = region.resize((box[2] - box[0], box[3] - box[1]))
im.paste(region,box)
im.show()
```