# Python - paste one image to another

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

### Goal:

In Python,(Using libraries Pillow and Numpy) I need to paste one picture, into another picture - to get a combined picture that, used pic1 as a center, and pic2 as background.

### This is pic1 and pic2:

[image][image]

[image]

### What I have tried:

```
from PIL import Image

pice_img = Image.open(f'{pices_path}')
tiles_img = Image.open(f'{tiles_path}')
final_img = tiles_img.copy() 
final_img.paste(pice_img, (0, 0))
final_img.save(f'{final_path})

np.asarray(pice_img).shape # (240, 240, 2)
np.asarray(tiles_img).shape # (240, 240, 4)
```

When I try to save final_img. I got this as a result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, or links you have read - (or tried) and we can easier help you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you composite an image onto another image with PIL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563822/how-do-you-composite-an-image-onto-another-image-with-pil-in-python)

Comment: @WilliamMartens I added in question, thanks!

Comment: this might help: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-paste/

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
tiles_img.paste(pice_img, (0, 0), pice_img)
```