# Choose the Layer you want to draw to in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In PIL, can you choose the layer where you want to draw, so you don't draw every time ontop of everything?
I am trying to draw an ellipse:

```
draw.ellipse(((0, 0), (200, 200)),fill=color)
```

which works just fine. But I want to draw another ellipse under the ellipse I just drew (drawing the next ellipse before the first ellipse isn't possible in my case). Can I set Layers or something, to draw an ellipse under another ellipse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you composite an image onto another image with PIL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563822/how-do-you-composite-an-image-onto-another-image-with-pil-in-python)

Comment: Just to summarize, no, PIL can't do layers, but it's easy to do your own. Just keep your own stack of image layers, and write a simple "composite" routine to combine them all with `paste`.